# Django urls space gets added after main url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I get this error message

```
Using the URLconf defined in esarcrm.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. ^person/ duplicate_check/(?P<entity>)/(?P<full_name>)/?$
2. ^admin/
3. ^api/v1/
4. ^api/v1/authenticate/$ [name='api_authenticate']
5. ^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
6. ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, person/duplicate_check/candidate/tom, didn't match any of these.
```

Please not the space here `1. ^person/[SPACE]duplicate_check`

my project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^person/', include('person.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/v1/authenticate/$', crm_views.ApiAuthenticateView.as_view(), name='api_authenticate'),
]
```

my app.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'duplicate_check/(?P<entity>)/(?P<full_name>)/?$', views.check_if_exist),
]
```

my app.views

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def check_if_exist(request, entity, first_name):
    if entity == 'candidate':
        candidates = person_models.Candidate.objects.filter(first_name=first_name)
        serializer = person_serializers.CandidateMiniSerializer(candidates, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: in ` urlpatterns` in your app urls you've forgot to put `^` like `r^'duplicate_check...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no space, that's just how Django prints the URLs.

The problem has nothing to do with spaces, but with your URL. "duplicate_check" is included under person/, but you are trying to access p_check/....

**Edit** There are actually bigger problems with your URL pattern. You haven't actually given the capturing groups anything to capture. You need some kind of pattern inside the parentheses. Something like:

```
r'^duplicate_check/(?P<entity>\w+)/(?P<full_name>\w+)/?$'
```

which will capture all alphanumeric characters for entity and full_name.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I actually had it correct in postman. still does not work